# Iterate through Array and use variables in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, dashing

Hey I am an absolute ruby noob and hope you could help me.
I want to do a lot of SQL-querys with different departments (Department A,B, C....)

I want to save the departments to an array and iteratethrough it, use loops and so on.

This is my old code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'mysql2'
##Connect to my Database
db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "MyUserName", :password => "MyPassword", :port => 3306, :database => "MyTest-Database" )

#Mysql querys
sql_A= "SELECT RMKPI FROM `Table1` WHERE `Department` = 'A' "
sql_B= "SELECT RMKPI FROM `Table1` WHERE `Department` = 'B' "

#Execute the querys
results_PO = db.query(sql_A)
results_DevMuM = db.query(sql_A)
```

This is my Pseudocode:

```
Array1[A,B,...]
loop
   sql_Array1[x]="SELECT ...WHERE `Department`= Array1[x]"
   Array1[x+1]
```

How can I do this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you you found the answer helpful you should consider selecting it.

Answer (score 2):

```
DEPARTMENTS = %w|A B C|
results = DEPARTMENTS.map do |department|
  query = "SELECT RMKPI FROM `Table1` WHERE `Department` = '#{department}'"
  [department, db.query(query)]
end.to_h
```

Now you have a hash of `{ departments ⇒ results }`. To access results for a given department, use:

```
results['A']
```

*Sidenote*: I would suggest you to google for `ActiveRecord` or any other ROM to simplify and make safer the work with database queries.